# Difficulty using Wiremock, microservices, and external https service - no traffic captured

Tags: https, proxy, mocking, microservices, wiremock

I have a system with microservice architecture. So I have a setup such that when I hit an URL, for example "http://localhost:8081/data/myId/" I get back a JSON response describing a resource. This is the system which I have created.

It turns out that there is some more complexity as to get this response, I am making a connection to an external service provider - this is what I want to use WireMock to mock, as this service provider has an API call limit. Let us say that I am interacting with this service provider at the following URL "https://api.dummyservice.com/". (So all "http://localhost:8081/data/myId/" calls consist of a "https://api.dummyservice.com/" call.)

So I am using WireMock as follows

```
java -jar '/home/user/Desktop/wiremock-standalone-2.19.0.jar'
--recd-mappings
--proxy-all https://api.dummyservice.com/
--verbose
--print-all-network-traffic
```

My intention is to listen to all calls at https://api.dummyservice.com/ through my microservice-based system so that I can stub and mock the responses. The problem is that I am not capturing any traffic at all when I access "http://localhost:8081/data/myId/" and get a successful response back!

Have I misunderstood WireMock's application? How can I debug this issue? It seems that I am performing quite a straightforward task.

I am on an Ubuntu 18.04 system if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you use standalone WireMock in a proper way, but please check correct params [here](http://wiremock.org/docs/running-standalone/)

```
--record-mappings
--proxy-all="https://api.dummyservice.com/"
```